# Running total over duplicate column values and no other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, t-sql

I want to do running total but there is no unique column or id column to be used in over clause.

```
CREATE TABLE piv2([name] varchar(5), [no] int);

INSERT INTO piv2
    ([name], [no])
VALUES
    ('a', 1),
    ('a', 2),
    ('a', 3),
    ('a', 4),
    ('b', 1),
    ('b', 2),
    ('b', 3);
```

there are only 2 columns, name which has duplicate values and the no on which I want to do running total in SQL Server 2017 .

expected result:

```
a 1
a 3
a 6
a 10
b 11
b 13
b 16
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query would generate the output you expect, at least for the exact sample data you did show us:

```
SELECT
    name,
    SUM(no) OVER (ORDER BY name, no) AS no_sum
FROM piv2;
```

If the order you intend to use for the rolling sum is something other than the order given by the `name` and `no` columns, then you should reveal that logic along with sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Check rows clause: it treats duplicates as distinct values.

```sql
sum(col2) over (order by col1 rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
```

Comment: Learn how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).